# When does two lines coincide?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces, vectors, linear-transformations

I was going through this book called "A Course in Mathematics for Students of Physics Volume 1 by Paul Bamberg and Shlomo Sternberg". There in a part they said something like this:

...if we start with a point P and write $$R = P “ + ” u$$ $$Q = P “ + ” v$$ and $$S = P “ + ” (u + v)$$ then the four points $$P, Q, S, R$$ lie at the four vertices of a parallelogram... The proof of this fact goes as follows. For any vector $$v = (a, b)$$ and any real number t defines their product tv by $$tv = (ta, tb)$$ if P is any point the set $$l = {P “ + ” tv}$$ (as t varies over real number), is a straight line passing through P. If R is some other point, then the line
$$m = {R “ + ”sv}$$ (as s varies over real number) and l will intersect, i.e., have some point in common, if and only if there are some $$s_1$$ and $$t_1$$ such that,
$$R “ + ” s_1v = P “ + ” t_1v$$
which means that
$$R = P “ + ” (t_1 - s_1)v$$
and hence, for every s, that
$$R “ + ”sv = P “ + ”(s + t_1 - s_1)v.$$
This means that the lines m and l coincide. In other words, either the lines l and m coincide or they do not intersect, i.e., either they are the same or they are
parallel...

Now what I don't understand is the last sentence, why m and l coincide? How can they say m and l coincide from the equation, $$R “ + ”sv = P “ + ”(s + t_1 - s_1)v$$?

Comment: What is $“+”$ (typed as `“+”`)? Never saw this before.

Comment: Two points uniquely determine a line so if two points are on two lines then the lines must be the same.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts the authors said, "If P is any point in the plane, we will denote the displaced point Q by P“+”v: the “ + ” is a symbol for this operation of vectors on points."

Answer (score 0):

In the last equation, the left hand side runs through all the points of $m$ as $s$ varies. The right hand side runs through all the points of $\ell$ too, because as $s$ runs through all of the reals so does $t = s + r_1 - s_1$.

I suggest you draw a picture and label each point on that common line with the values of $s$ and $t$ to see geometrically what this algebra is saying.

Comment: But how $$t=s+r_1-s_1$$ ?

Comment: @Plague  Work out some numerical examples. Pick a line. Pick a point on that line. Then describe the line two ways, with different vectors $u$ and $v$. See how the parameterizations are related.

Answer (score 0):

See this part:

> if and only if there are some $s_1$ and $t_1$ such that $$R+s_1v=P+t_1v$$ [...]

The two sides of the proposed equality $R+s_1v$ and $P+t_1v$ are *some* points of lines $m$ and $l$, respectively.

If the equality holds, then they are *the same* point – a common point of the two lines. And due to the same $v$ vector, the lines have the same direction. Hence they coincide.